# I can't run vue project with Nuxt Fatal Error

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

When I run `npm start` I am getting an error.

```
 FATAL  No build files found in ..\client\.nuxt\dist\server. Use either `nuxt build` or `builder.build()` or start nuxt in development mode.

Use either `nuxt build` or `builder.build()` or start nuxt in development mode.
at VueRenderer._ready (node_modules\@nuxt\vue-renderer\dist\vue-renderer.js:758:13)
at async Server.ready (node_modules\@nuxt\server\dist\server.js:637:5)
at async Nuxt._init (node_modules\@nuxt\core\dist\core.js:482:7)

Nuxt Fatal Error
Error: No build files found in ..\client\.nuxt\dist\server.
Use either `nuxt build` or `builder.build()` or start nuxt in development mode.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! client@1.0.0 start: `nuxt start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the client@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Vue version is `@vue/cli 4.5.13`.
I am vue.js beginner. What is reason? How can I fix it?
Thank you.

Comment: Try deleting the `..\client\.nuxt` folder and follow @fevid answer
If that doesnt work, try updating/upgrading vue/nuxt packages
If that doesnt work, try removing packages from your package.json; 1 by 1 until the issue resolves.  (Good idea to have backups before you start messing arround)

Comment: There is not .nuxt folder

Comment: Try the other 2 suggestions  i mentioned in the prior comment

Comment: ```No build files found in ..\client\.nuxt\dist\server``` - the error is self explanatory. As a developer try to read error messages. Good luck !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `npm run build` after that you can use `npm start`.
alternatively, if you are developing and are not in production use `npm run dev`.